# Python string.replace does not replace

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, markdown

I have the following code.

```
    def render_markdown(markdown):
        "Replaces markdown links with plain text"
        # non greedy
        # also includes images
        RE_ANCHOR = re.compile(r"\[[^\[]*?\]\(.+?\)")
        # create a mapping
        mapping = load_mapping()
        anchors = RE_ANCHOR.findall(markdown)
        counter = -1
        while len(anchors) != 0:
            for link in anchors:
                counter += 1
                text, href = link.split('](')[:2]
                text = '-=-' + text[1:] + '-=-'
                text = text.replace(' ', '_') + '_' + str(counter)
                href = href[: -1]
                mapping[text] = href
                markdown = markdown.replace(link, text)
                anchors = RE_ANCHOR.findall(markdown)
        return markdown, mapping
```

However the markdown function does not replace all the links. Almost none are replaced.I looked around on SO and found a lot of questions pertaining to this. The problems found were of the type:

```
    abc.replace(x, y) instead of abc = abc.replace(x, y)
```

I am doing that but the string is not being replaced

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [many markdown libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=markdown&submit=search) available to install ready to go?

Comment: @kindall This is an effort to educate myself. Hence I am building from scratch. I am expecting [search](https://google.com) to be replaced with -=-search-=-

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cause is that your regex isn't matching the text you expected.  So the loop is empty.

Try posting some sample markdown, run your code, and add *print* statements so that you can see all the intermediate results (especially the *anchors* list).  With that in hand, debugging will be much easier :-)

Comment: I have verified with adding print statements all along the function. Each link is being found by the reg-ex as expected. However the return value of the replace function is the same as the original provided. This is not consistent. Sometimes it replaces sometimes it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't post your sample data and expected output, it is hard to give you meaningful help.  The usual reason that  ``replace(old, new)`` doesn't replace anything is that there is no exact match for *old*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `replace` when you are already using regex. The `re` library gives you the tools to do what you want without needing to locate the string twice (once with the regex and once with `replace`).

For example, [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) contains the [`start` and `end`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) positions of the matched text. You could use text slicing to do your own string substitutions. But even that is unnecessary as you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and have the `re` library do the substitution for you when a match is found. You just need to define a callable which accepts the MathObject and returns the text to replace it.

```
def render_markdown(markdown):
    "Replaces markdown links with plain text"

    RE_ANCHOR = re.compile(r"\[[^\[]*?\]\(.+?\)")

    mapping = load_mapping()

    def replace_link(m):
        # process your link here...
        mapping[text] = href
        return text

    return RE_ANCHOR.sub(replace_link, markdown)
```

And if you wanted to make a few additions to your regular expression, you could have the regex break up your link into parts which would be accessible as groups on the match object. For example:

```
RE_ANCHOR = re.compile(r"\[([^\[]*?)\]\((.+?)\)")

# ...

text = m.group(1)
link = m.group(2)
```

All I did was add a set of parentheses around each of the text and link (inside the brackets). Although, I expect your regex is not sophisticated enough to match all possible links found within Markdown documents. For example, the [Python-Markdown](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/blob/master/markdown/inlinepatterns.py#L129) library permits at least six levels of nested brackets inside the "text" portion of the link. And don't forget about titles defined in a link (as `(url "title")`). But that is just scratching the surface. Besides, that would be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about the nested brackets. I will get to them eventually. As of now I have changed the code to use the way you have described. However I still do not understand why the replace was not happening. Unless there was a flaw in my code, the logic was pretty clear and unambiguous. The only fault was that it was not efficient. Thanks for the help anyways. :D